# Error - The type System.Xml.IXmlLineInfo is not found in System.Xml?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, t4

We recently upgraded our Development environment from Visual Studion 2010 to 2013.

Now, whenever I try to run one specific T4 template I get the following error message:

```
Compiling transformation: The type System.Xml.IXmlLineInfo is defined in an assembly the is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken= ...'.
```

Surprisingly my searches haven't turned up anything specific to this error version (4.0.0.0). I have see a few suggestions related to version 2.0 that haven't offered any information I am not already using.

I have made sure to add **System.Xml** (Version 4.0.0.0) to my project References, and I have included the following in the top of my template file:

```
<#@ import namespace="System.Xml" #> 
<#@ import namespace="System.Xml.dll" #> 
<#@ import namespace="System.Xml.IXmlLineInfo" #>
```

The [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.ixmllineinfo%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) says that this Interface is absolutely defined in System.Xml v4, and furthermore both of my colleagues are experiencing it too.

Has anyone else had this error?

Any information is well appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the fix!

I needed to add this line above the ***import***:

```
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Xml" #>
```

This should've been obvious enough, though for some reason we were not required to do it in the last version.

Hope this helps anyone else who has the same error!